# How to concatenate 360° videos with FFmpeg?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I have some video mp4 files that I need to concatenate. I'm working with FFmpeg (self-built version N-93863-g58d167b) under Ubuntu Linux 18.04. I found a lot of information about this, but nothing that works with 360°  video format. What I have tried so far:

`ffmpeg -i file1.mp4 -i file2.mp4 -f concat -c copy outfile.mp4`

that complains that `Line 4: unknown keyword 'ftypisom' file1.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input`

`ffmpeg -i file1.mp4 -i file2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v] [0:a] [1:v] [1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" outfile.mp4` (as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232/how-to-concatenate-two-mp4-files-using-ffmpeg))

but, because it re-encodes the file, it loses the 360° format and makes it just flat.

I tried with the `-strict unofficial` parameter, with the `-fflags keepside`, `-map_metadata 0` (as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44760588/preserving-side-data-information-for-360-video-transcoding-using-ffmpeg)) and with several other combination of -c:v (copy, h264, h265, ...),  as well as with .mkv as file type, all to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can't test but it should be `ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -c copy -strict -1 outfile.mp4` where list.txt is in the form shown at https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer

Comment: @Gyan That didn't work either: it doesn't give any error (but a lot of warnings), but it flattens the video out again and introduces some other codification artifacts.